# Placeholder Not working well

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just wanna ask anyone here knows why when i put a placeholder in my masterpage it became like this

```
[ PlaceHolder "PlaceHolder1" ]
```

It supposed to be a blank editable box right? I cant even write anything there.
Help me ya. Thank you.

Comment: It acts as a container for controls to be added ? i believe you want to add a textbox to the placeholder for it to behave as you desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) instead of [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx).

> Use the `PlaceHolder` control as a container to store server controls
>   that are dynamically added to the Web page. The `PlaceHolder` control
>   **does not produce any visible output** and is used only **as a container**
>   for other controls on the Web page.

When `ContentPlaceHolder` is used to hold content from Content Pages and can only be used on a Master Page

Comment: Thank you alex. U helped me with amazing answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **Content Place Holder** rather than placeholder

Answer (score -1):

1. A placeholder is used to reserve some place for dynamically added controls
2. It is not a blank editable textbox
3. If you need a textbox for editing, just drop a simple server side textbox control & set its text mode to multiline inside properties.
   [W3Schools:ASP.NET Placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_placeholder.asp)